# Source code compiled from a Repository() is not put in the variant dir for a Hierarchical SCons project

Tags: build, scons

I have a Hierarchical project that uses source code from a common system-directory, for which I am using the SCons `Repository()` function and want all the build output (local code and code taken from the Repository) placed in a variant_dir.

If I use the `Repository()` function in a simple scenario (non-hierchical with no calls to sub-directory SConscripts) then the compiled Repository() object file is placed in the variant_dir as expected. But if I do the same in a hierarchical build, the compiled `Repository()` object file is placed in the project root directory.

Assuming I want to use the following source code located in a system-directory:

```
/usr/local/repoDir/repoFile.cc
```

And I have the following project structure:

```
# tree .
.
|-- SConstruct
|-- build
|   `-- linux_x86_64
`-- moduleA
    |-- localFile.cc
    `-- SConscript
```

Here are the build scripts:

SConstruct

**Edit:** Removed filename from call to Repository(), thanks to Dirk Baechle from users@scons.tigris.org for pointing that out.

```
env = Environment()

env.Repository('/usr/local/repoDir')

env['variantDir'] = 'build/linux_x86_64'

SConscript('moduleA/SConscript',
           exports = ['env'],
           variant_dir = env['variantDir'],
           duplicate = 0)
```

moduleA/SConscript

```
import os

Import('env')

srcFiles = [
  'localFile.cc',
  #os.path.join(env['variantDir'], 'repoFile.cc'),          # fails to find source file
  #'#%s' % os.path.join(env['variantDir'], 'repoFile.cc'),  # fails to find source file
  #'repoFile.cc',                                           # fails to find source file
  '#repoFile.cc',  # only option that works, but places object in root proj dir
]

env.Append(CPPPATH = ['.', '#'])
env.Program(target = 'myApp', source = srcFiles)
```

I would like the `repoFile.cc` file to be compiled and have its object file placed in `build/linux_x86_64`, but instead its placed in the same directory as the root SConstruct.

As you can see from the comments in `moduleA/SConscript`, I tried referencing the `repoFile.cc` several different ways, and the only way that worked is as mentioned therein. Additionally, I tried calling the `Repository()` function in `moduleA/SConscript`, but it didnt change anything.

**Edit**: Here is the compilation output

```
# scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o repoFile.o -c -Ibuild/linux_x86_64 -ImoduleA -I/usr/local/repoDir/moduleA -I/usr/local/repoDir/build/linux_x86_64 -I. -I/usr/local/repoDir /usr/local/repoDir/repoFile.cc
g++ -o build/linux_x86_64/localFile.o -c -Ibuild/linux_x86_64 -ImoduleA -I/usr/local/repoDir/moduleA -I/usr/local/repoDir/build/linux_x86_64 -I. -I/usr/local/repoDir moduleA/localFile.cpp
g++ -o build/linux_x86_64/myApp build/linux_x86_64/localFile.o repoFile.o
scons: done building targets.
```

And resulting directory structure:

```
# tree .
.
|-- repoFile.o    <=== This file should be in build/linux_x86_64 NOT here
|-- SConstruct
|-- build
|   `-- linux_x86_64
|       |-- localFile.o
|       `-- myApp
`-- moduleA
    |-- localFile.cpp
    `-- SConscript
```

I checked around and found this, but its not quite the same:

[Scons Hierarchical Builds with Repository directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4043689/1158895)

Any suggestions as to how I can get the object file in the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this same question on the SCons-users mailing list, and received some information that partly answers this question. Thanks to `Dirk Baechle` for helping me with this issue.

The `Repository()` function effectively *mounts* the directory passed in to the root of the SCons project: that is to the directory where the `SConstruct` file is. If files in a repo sub-directory need to be referenced in sub-directories of the SCons project, then the sub-directory names (that of the repo dir and scons project dir) must match. That's why the different options in the `SConscript` file in the question above fail to find the repo file.

If the repo sub-directory `moduleA` existed with the file `repoFile.cc`, then it would be found as expected and the compiled object would be placed in the variant_dir as expected.

One limitation I see to the `Repository()` function is that you can't *mount* the repo directory to a SCons project sub-directory. This sounds like a feature request.

The fact that SCons places the compiled object file in the source directory seems like a bug to me. At the very least, it should be placed in the variant_dir root directory.