# How to get the target generated from Repository() path in to Variant_dir path instead of Sconstruct folder

Tags: build, scons

I am able to locate the specific file by giving the path in Repository().
But the output generated is in the Sconstruct directory instead of in the 
variant_dir.

### Please let me know how to resolve this issue

Explaining the problem specifically
The tree structure in the project looks as below.

## tree .

```
.
|-- SConstruct
|--Build
|   `-- SConscript_unitTest
|--FileB_mock.o
|--FileA.o 
|-- _Output
|   `-- unit_test
|        |--FileA_unittest.o    
`-- moduleA
|   |-- FileA.cpp
|   `-- UnitTest
|       |-- FileA_unittest.cpp
|        `-- SConscript
`-- moduleB
|   |-- FileB.cpp
|   `-- UnitTest
|       |-- FileB_unittest.cpp
|        `-- SConscript
`-- Mocks
     `-- moduleA
     |   |-- FileA_mock.cpp 
     |   `-- FileA_mock.h
     `-- moduleB
         |-- FileB_mock.cpp 
         `-- FileB_mock.h
```

For the above structure,

1. In the SConstruct i make the call to SConscript_unitTest.
2. Implementation of Sconscript_unitTest is

   > 'SConscript('#\moduleA\UnitTest\SConscript',
   >                variant_dir = '#_Output\unit_test'), duplicate=0)'
3. Implementation of moduleA\UnitTest\Sconscript is

   > Sources = [ 'FileA_unittest.cpp',
   >               '#FileB_mock.cpp',
   >               '#FileA.cpp'
   >             ]

   ```
   Repository( '#\ModuleA', '#\Mocks\ModuleB')
   obj_files = Object(Sources)
   Program(target_name, obj_files)
   ```
4. As shown in the Heirarchical diagram, FileA_unittest.o falls in the intended variant_dir, but FileB_mock.o and FileA.o are in the root folder.
5. I am not sure what i have done here is the best mechanism .. as i am translating an existing make project to scons.
   Hope i have given enough detail of the problem.

Comment: Sure, but please let us all know *how* exactly you're trying to accomplish things. This means you have to show your full SConstruct/SConscripts in a minimal working example (MWE) that demonstrates the problem, such that others can reproduce it on their machines and try to help you out. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: My issue is the same as explained in the link below                   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209961/source-code-compiled-from-a-repository-is-not-put-in-the-variant-dir-for-a-hie?lq=1)

Comment: And you are asking it again (duplicate?) because...?

Comment: It was not asked by me the first time ... to me it looks the solution was not provided there ... also as i am a new user i dont have the option to put any comment on that link :(

Comment: The solution mentioned in the link is ... **_If files in a repo sub-directory need to be referenced in sub-directories of the SCons project, then the sub-directory names (that of the repo dir and scons project dir) must match._**   Does this mean i need to create in my variant_dir path equivalent repository empty folders?

Comment: I have now provided a MWE ... hoping to get a response.

Comment: Question: in your `moduleA\UnitTest\Sconscript` why do you prepend a "`#`" to the last two source files?

Comment: And you added the embedded tag - why? Read the tag-descriptions before adding!

Comment: The location of the two files are specified by the Repository(), if i dont add the # to these two files they are not recognised by the build.

Comment: Your assumption is not correct. Adding "../../" would work too, for example. But what you're mainly after is to use the Repository() method as `Repository('Mocks')`, please reread the description of this method in the MAN page. You probably also need to use "duplicate=1", again read up on what this does in contrast to the "duplicate=0" that you have at the moment, please.

Comment: Thanks, i will go through them and check

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response ... i didnt had to use repository() just restrucured the project to do the intended task.